# How to change the tensor shape in middle layers?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, nlp, embedding, word-embedding

Saying I have a 2000x100 matrix, I put it into 10 dimension embedding layer, which gives me 2000x100x10 tensor. so it's 2000 examples and each example has a 100x10 matrix. and then, I pass it to a conv1d and KMaxpolling to get 2000x24 matrix, which is 2000 examples and each example has a 24 dimension vector. and now, I would like to recombine those examples before I apply another layer. I would like to combine the first 10 examples together, and such and such, so I get a tuple. and then I pass that tuple to the next layer.
My question is, Can I do that with Keras? and any idea on how to do it?

Comment: Yes, you can do it using both tensorflow and keras. Your structure is not clear. My suggestion is to start with some pre-implemented small example and then come back with specific problem to your scenario. There are plenty of codes on github. Just google it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea of using "samples" is that these samples should be unique and not relate to each other.

This is something Keras will demand from your model: if it started with 2000 samples, it must end with 2000 samples. Ideally, these samples do not talk to each other, but you can use custom layers to hack this, but only in the middle. You will need to end with 2000 samples anyway.

I believe you're going to end your model with 200 groups, so maybe you should already start with shape `(200,10,100)` and use `TimeDistributed` wrappers:

```
inputs = Input((10,100))                       #shape (200,10,100)
out = TimeDistributed(Embedding(....))(inputs) #shape (200,10,100,10)
out = TimeDistributed(Conv1D(...))(out)        #shape (200,10,len,filters)

#here, you use your layer that will work on the groups without TimeDistributed.
```

To reshape a tensor without changing the batch size, use the `Reshape(newShape)` layer, where `newShape` does not include the first dimension (batch size).

To reshape a tensor including the batch size, use a `Lambda(lambda x: K.reshape(x,newShape))` layer, where `newShape` includes the first dimension (batch size)    - Here you must remember the warning above: somewhere you will need to undo this change so you end up with the same batch size as the input.

Comment: yes, I start with 2000 samples. since I want to go through an embedding layer, I form those matrices to vectors. pass it through the embedding and I transform to the original shape again.

Comment: I have one more question. what if my shape for each sample is different? saying I have (10,100) for first example, and (5,100) for second one?

Comment: You can use `None` in the input shape for the varying dimension, but you will need to train separately because you can't put all samples in the same array. Also, your layers and calculations must support variable dimensions.

Comment: Actually, I have one dimension fixed. only one dimension varying. Do you have any idea on which function I may use?

Comment: I don't know what you want to do.

Comment: I have 
model = Sequential()
inputs = Input(shape = (None,148))
out = model.add(TimeDistributed(Embedding(vocabulary_size,embedding_dim)))(inputs)
output1 = model.predict(x_train) 
but I get error:
'NoneType' object is not callable